# How to perform zip-like operations on two RDDs of different number of elements in each partition?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm using Spark 1.1.0.

I have 2 RDDs `firstSample` and `secondSample` of type `JavaRDD<IndividualBean>`. The contents of these RDDs is as follows:

```
[
IndividualBean [params={...}], 
IndividualBean [params={...}], 
IndividualBean [params={...}]
]

[
IndividualBean [params={...}], 
IndividualBean [params={...}], 
IndividualBean [params={...}]
]
```

When I try to `zip` them together, I get the following error:

> Can only zip RDDs with same number of elements in each partition

I guess that this is because my RDDs do not have the same number of partitions, or the same number of elements per partition.

I would like to perform an operation on these RDDs that will give me the same results as `zip`.

Right now, I found the following solution (with the `totalSize` variable just being the size of `firstSample.union(secondSample)`):

```
JavaPairRDD<IndividualBean, IndividualBean> zipped = firstSample.union(secondSample).zipWithIndex().mapToPair(
            new PairFunction<Tuple2<IndividualBean,Long>, Long, IndividualBean>() {
                @Override
                public Tuple2<Long, IndividualBean> call(
                        Tuple2<IndividualBean, Long> tuple) throws Exception {
                    return new Tuple2<Long, IndividualBean>(tuple._2, tuple._1);
                }
    }).groupBy(new Function<Tuple2<Long,IndividualBean>, Long>() {
        @Override
        public Long call(Tuple2<Long, IndividualBean> tuple) throws Exception {
            long index = tuple._1.longValue();
            if(index < totalSize/2){
                return index+totalSize/2;
            }
            return index;
        }
    }).values().mapToPair(new PairFunction<Iterable<Tuple2<Long, IndividualBean>>, IndividualBean, IndividualBean>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<IndividualBean, IndividualBean> call(
                Iterable<Tuple2<Long, IndividualBean>> iterable) throws Exception {
            Iterator<Tuple2<Long, IndividualBean>> it = iterable.iterator();
            IndividualBean firstBean = it.next()._2;
            IndividualBean secondBean = it.next()._2;
            return new Tuple2<IndividualBean, IndividualBean>(firstBean, secondBean);
        }
    });
```

But it is quite expensive, since it involves shuffling.

What could be a better way to do this?

Comment: I think you need to step back and think about _why_ these RDDs are partitioned differently. Is it by accident or because you need them to be? As long as they're partitioned differently ANY method of zipping them is going to require a lot of communication and hence will be expensive. It may make sense to make sure they're identically partitioned from the start, or to re-partition one or both of them at some point, depending on your application.  If you give us more background it'll be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: Well, basically, I have a population a IndividualBean. Then I randomly take (using sample) at most half the subset of this population (subset A), and compare each individual in this subset A, to another individual contained in the remaining subset (I make sure this remaining subset B is of the same size as subset A).

Comment: This process of comparing individuals is part of a selection process in a genetic algorithm. The zip operation allows me to do this comparison, but since I randomly choose individuals to be compared, I always end up with non compatible(# number of partitions,# number of elements/partition) subsets involved.

Comment: Are you willing to accept the constraint that each of the pairs takes both elements from the same partition? Then it should be possible to create your zip (using one of the overloads of zipPartitions) without any communication whatsoever. Subsets A and B would probably be computed using mapPartitions and some trickery.

Comment: Thanks a lot, how can I obtain a JavaPairRDD<IndividualBean, IndividualBean> at the end using mapPartitions and zipPartitions? could you show me how I can code this solution?

Comment: Apologies for giving you the answer in Scala -- it's all I had time for right now. Happy to help you with the Java solution if needed but it will take me longer. (I'm very familiar with Java but have never used it in Spark.)

Answer (score 0):

A solution in Scala because that's how I've dome all my Spark programming.

The key to this solution is to keep the same partitioning scheme throughout, and then zip the individual partitions together. To achieve this the solution plays fast and loose with sampling. In particular, the   data point paired with each randomly chosen point is:

1. Chosen from the same partition
2. Not chosen at random (in fact will tend to have come from right next to it in the original RDD)

The first of these simplifications is essential to the solution. The second could be removed by adding some code to the `zipFunc` defined below to reorder one side of the zip.

It's important to understand what zipFunc does: I'm zipping together the sample and its complement, and these are not even the same size. I trivially zip up the contents of corresponding partitions in the two RDDs and even though they don't have the same number of samples: when I run out of samples on one side of the zip I just drop the ones on the other side.

```
val testRDD = sc.parallelize(1 to 1000, 4)

val firstSample = testRDD.sample(false, 0.4)
val remaining = testRDD.subtract(firstSample)

def zipFunc(l: Iterator[Int], r: Iterator[Int]) : Iterator[(Int,Int)] = {
  val res = new ListBuffer[(Int, Int)]
  // exercise for the reader: suck either l or r into a container before iterating 
  // and consume it in random order to achieve more random pairing if desired
  while (l.hasNext && r.hasNext) {
    res += ((l.next(), r.next()))
  }
  res.iterator
}
// notice the `true` to make sure partitioning is preserved
val pairs:RDD[(Int,Int)] = firstSample.zipPartitions(remaining, true)(zipFunc)
```

As far as I can tell this requires no cross-partition communication. It does depend on your samples
being drawn fairly evenly from across the partitions, and in my experience the `sample()` method is not too bad in this regard.

Comment: This code is easy to understand, I won't have difficulties to translate it in Java. I will git it a try, thanks!

Comment: Something I noticed playing around with this some more is that the `subtract()` call seems to introduce communication, and adding a second parameter specifying the same number of partitions doesn't seem to help. Another way to achieve the same thing, if it matters to you, is again to use `zipPartitions()` for set difference. But you may have your own method for generating the second set -- you just need to make sure it's got the same number of partitions.

Comment: The second set has indeed the same number of partitions. By the way, the boolean parameter in zipPartitions method does not seem to be available anymore (at least in java). Also, I got wierd results (zipPartitions return en empty rdd even if both samples are not empty) with the zipFunc function(the same I got using standard zip function). I'm wondering if this is because we drop samples when both iterator are not of the same size. I need to investigate more to understand what's happening here.